# Pure conduit for an impure but effectless computation

Tags: haskell, streaming, conduit, unsafe-perform-io

I am trying to do something like this:

```hs
processListIO :: [A] -> IO [B]
processListIO xs = bracket ini fin $ \s -> mapM (upd s) xs
  where
    ini :: IO (Ptr S)
    upd :: Ptr S -> A -> IO B
    fin :: Ptr S -> IO ()
```

Basically, this is a computation that iterates over a list, maps each element to something else, and uses an internal private state in the process. The specific `ini`, `upd`, and `fin` I have in mind come from a C library, but they are guaranteed to “behave well” in that they just allocate fresh state, perform a computation whose only side-effect is modifying the state, and then deallocate the state. I believe, this means I can safely put `unsafePerformIO` in front and get a pure function:

```hs
processList :: [A] -> [B]
processList = unsafePerformIO . processListIO
```

Now I would like to do the same, but with `conduit` (or, actually, any other streaming library). However, since the computation is essentially effectless I would like my conduit to be pure:

```hs
processStream :: ConduitT A B Identity ()
```

or even better:

```hs
processStream :: forall m. Monad m => ConduitT A B m ()
```

(I suspect the latter might make no sense, because it seems that the trick works so well with simple lists only because the elements are pure.)

Ideally, I want to completely hide from the user the fact that the computation needs a state and makes foreign calls, and just pretend that it is merely something like a `scanl` (or [`mapAccum`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.3.3/docs/Data-Conduit-List.html#v:mapAccum), as `conduit` calls it).

Is this possible? How do I do this with `conduit` (or some other streaming library)?

Comment: You should always be able to turn a `Conduit` over `Identity` into one over an arbitrary `Monad`. I would expect the `conduit` package to offer such a function, but I haven't checked.

Comment: @dfeuer On the one hand, yes, this is just `hoist (pure . runIdentity)` (as long as you have `hoist`). However, I can’t explain why, but, taking into account that monads are so diverse (e.g. all kinds of branching computations) and given that resource allocation/cleanup is involved, it just doesn’t sound right. With `Identity` it’s easy, you allocate in the beginning and clean up in the end, but what if your monad is `ListT IO`?

Comment: Actually, this brings another concern. I clearly need to use some sort of `bracket` in the implementation of my conduit, but `Identity` is neither `MonadMask`, nor `MonadResource`.

Comment: There is `transPipe`, which looks `hoist`-adjacent. A conduit over `Identity` can't really need any cleanup, can it?

Comment: I suspect your need for bracketing is going to cause you some pretty fundamental problems, but I'm not super-familiar with `conduit`.

Comment: @kirelagin: I’m not really familiar with conduit (not even sure how you convert `[A] -> [B]` to a conduit/pipe), but I wonder if you could use `unsafeIOToST` on the inside and `runST` around it? That might be a bit better behaved re. sequencing stuff properly internally but appearing pure externally.

Comment: @kirelagin You've got it backwards. `Identity` can be reinterpreted into any `Monad` `m`, period. If you have something you think lives in `Identity`, but can't imagine how it'd be interpreted into a certain monad (in your case, `[]`), then that thing doesn't live in `Identity`. If your library happens to have a way to duplicate its state, then you could probably properly implement the `Identity` version by allocating state at the start, *duplicating* and updating on input, and finalizing on garbage collection, but otherwise you "really are" living in your own special monad.

Comment: @HTNW well, yes, but we are talking here not about reinterpreting `Identity` as `m` but rather about reinterpreting `f Identity` as `f m` (where `f` in our case is `ConduitT ...`).

As I mentioned right in my fist comment, you can do this as long as you have `hoist`, i.e. if your monad transformer is a functor in the category of monads, and not all of them a (see e.g. `ContT`). As it turns out, `ConduitT` has `hosit` (which is called `transPipe`), however the mere existence of the function does not guarantee that it is correct (although, I suspect, it is).

Comment: @kirelagin ? Same difference: `ConduitT i o Identity r` translates to `ConduitT i o m r` for any `Monad m`, simply by replacing `return`/`Identity` with `return` in `m` "at every layer". If you can't imagine this working, then you don't have a `ConduitT i o Identity`. The problem you envision with the translation to `[]` (the necessity of duplicating the C library's state at every update) is also (perhaps more directly) demonstrated in the posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

> However, since the computation is essentially effectless I would like my conduit to be pure:
>
> ```
> processStream :: ConduitT A B Identity ()
> ```

You shouldn't do this because it breaks referential transparency. The conduit you want to construct would consume an `A` and produce a `B` right after, and repeat. From that conduit you can construct a function `A -> B` by restricting it to the first iteration, except that would not be pure, since calling that function again will make a new call to the stateful C library.

The purity of your first function `processList` comes from the fact that in a single application of that function you know all of the calls you are going to make to the C library. If you try to make it a conduit, you lose that control.

Anyway, unlike pure vs impure functions, there is no benefit to a pure conduit `ConduitT A B Identity` compared to an impure one `ConduitT A B M` which makes the required resources explicit.

Instead, I would suggest to wrap your C functions in an abstract monad to prevent users to capture the library state:

```hs
-- Safe interface
newtype M a          -- abstract, internally defined as (Ptr S -> IO a)
consume :: A -> M B
runM :: M a -> a     -- safe if the only way to construct (M a) values is using 'consume' and the 'Monad' instance.
```

Then you can easily wrap `consume` in a `ConduitT A B M Void` ([use `mapM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.3.3/docs/Data-Conduit-Combinators.html#v:mapM)). As far as I can tell, there is no good reason to want that `M` to be an `Identity`. Streaming libraries are designed to be usable in a way that's independent of the underlying resource (`M` or `Identity`).